# Multiple pattern matches with same input variable

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, match, case

I oftentimes face the following problem:

```
val b = a match {
  case Some(a) => "1"
  case None => "n"
}
val c = a match {
  case Some(a) => "2"
  case None => "n"
}
```

Obviously, the match is executed twice even though it is only necessary once. How can I make sure the compiler takes this into account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there will be any performance gain but you can write your code like this:

```
val (b, c) = a match {
  case Some(a) => ("1","2)
  case None => ("n", "n")
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but what if the after=>-parts are multilined? How would I handle this?

Comment: For the code written it's a performance _loss_ because the match is really fast, but it's nonetheless a good way to reflect that two new values depend on one old one.  So it's probably the superior pattern to use in the absence of performance concerns (or with something that is slow to match).

Comment: Just my opinion, I think that pattern matching an option is usually unnecessarily verbose. What about doing that ? a.map(_ => ("1", "2")).getOrElse( ("n","n") )

Comment: +1... I want to do one more +1 for the username and the icon :)

Comment: @vtheron: For me, pattern matching gives a well-arranged structure to the code. How would you write multilined code with `getOrElse`?

Comment: It depends on how complex your code is. With your example it's very trivial so map/getOrElse is enough. And you can perfectly put a block in map and getOrElse.

Comment: Even though sometimes I am lazy enough to prefer one-liners, I tend to prefer pattern match for short pieces of code because of its readability, stylishness (!) and familiarity.

Comment: @TejaKantamneni OK, me too.

Answer (score 1):

Matches can be extremely fast--comparable to an if-statement.  Don't worry about doing the work twice unless it's a difficult match.

It's slightly easier to match a default than another case, so if you really don't need the parameter your best bet is

```
val b = a match { case None => "n"; case _ => "1" }
val c = a match { case None => "n"; case _ => "2" }
```

This will often even outperform a mutable solution like

```
var b,c = "n"
a match { case Some(_) => b = "1"; c = "2"; case _ => }
```

and will certainly outperform any tuple-creation.

If the match is a time-consuming one then you have to store your results and return them in a tuple or other suitable data structure, as om-nom-nom has already demonstrated.  This may also be more clear, depending on context.

Comment: Typing it twice is also twice the work. :) Thanks for the reminder to be aware of extra allocations, as a matter of performance style (as a habit, something to do way in advance of profiling).